# Change PrimeFaces dialog to be modal on client side

Tags: javascript, primefaces, dialog, modal-dialog, client-side

I have a primefaces dialog like this:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" width="320" height="220" modal="false" closable="false" showHeader="false" resizable="false" position="right,top">
```

If I click on some element in my page I want to change this dialog to be modal. Is there a client side API for this?

Tried

```
onclick="dlg.setModal(true);"
```

with no success. Method setModal() does not exist.
Is it possible to change a dialog this way without roundtrip to the server?

Answer (score 0):

You have attribute for this (modal) now it false set it madal="true"

Comment: Then it is modal at creation time. The challenge is to have a non modal dialog changing to modal without server roundtrip, only client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Firefox with Firebug or some other browser / web developer tool that can show you the DOM element `dlg`?

There you can find that `dlg` has the methods `show()` and `hide()`, as well as `enableModality()`and `disableModality()`. These are (almost) what you want.

Unfortunately, `enable...` and `disable` don't (as one might think) set an option that makes the dialog become modal when shown. Rather they show or hide the "blackout" div. So when you want a dynamically modal dialog, instead of calling `dlg.show()` via Javascript, call `dlg.enableModality(); dlg.show()`, and vice versa for hiding.

**Edit:**

There is also the property `dlg.cfg` which contains some settings. It appears that if you simply set `dlg.cfg.modal=true` (whether that setting exists at the time or not), then the next time `dlg` is shown, it's modal (but, unlike setting it in your xhtml, it will still be draggable and resizable).